# Avoid transformation for child objects in easel js container

Tags: html, html5-canvas, easeljs

I am using easel js for working with a drawing application and have functionality like resize rotate etc. For a task I need to write a letter on  a image and used a container and added image and text as children.

Now the issue if I transform the container I don't need to reverse the letter only image.

I am using the following link for transformation:
https://github.com/senocular/TransformTool

Attach: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxg84liohd24knh/Untitled.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to target the sub-content, you can un-transform it simply using:

```
// Simple un-flip
clip.subClip.scaleX = 1/clip.scaleX;
```

If you need more complex un-transforms, you might need to spend some time on the math to do that for each property, or look into Matrix transformations.

The easiest way is to decouple the element from the container. Have it be a sibling that updates its position to match. This gives you much better control over the display.